# Reporting Services Textbox Format Question

Tags: reporting-services

I am creating a report with Reporting Services and am using several text boxes horizontally aligned next to each other.  I would like to put periods so that report looks like:

```
1234  Robert Jones................... (234) 921-4922  
1235  Jennifer Wilson................ (919) 582-2914
```

Is this possible to right-pad the text box with periods, or would I need to roll out some code to accomplish the above effect.

I tried doing this and the results looked like:

```
1234  Robert Jones...............     (234) 921-4922  
1235  Jennifer Wilson..........       (919) 582-2914
```

Is something like this even possible?

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to have 3 text boxes per line, with padding in the middle and allow the right side to truncate

The other way would be to use a monospace font and count the number of characters

Comment: Sorry, you just let the textbox itself truncate when it can't show an more text.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this was:

Set the CanGrow property to false and set the padding property on the top and margin to 3pt.  Depending on the height and width of your textboxes, your mileage may vary.